# No matching version found for gulp-sourcemaps@1.7.0

Tags: reactjs, npm

When running `npm install`

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for gulp-sourcemaps@1.7.0
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are 
requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget 
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'react-map-gl'
npm ERR! notarget
```

I was trying to install specified version by `npm install -g gulp-sourcemaps@1.7.0` or without `-g` option. Still no luck with this one.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my colleague suggested adding that dependency into `package.json`

```
"react-map-gl": {
  "version": "^1.2.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.7.0"
  }
},
```

Adding this and then running `npm install` fixed my problem. Which I think is weird when error says it's already specified.